# d3 layout is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Trying to use [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) and not sure how to reference it properly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<<<<other scripts>>>
<script src="topbar.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var n = 4, // number of layers
        m = 64, // number of samples per layer
     data = d3.layout.stack()(stream_layers(n, m, .1)),
    color = d3.interpolateRgb("#aad", "#556");
});
</script>
</head>
...
</html>
```

Comment: in the same way you have referenced other js

Comment: **See here for v4+:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337997/d3-js-v4-d3-layout-tree-has-been-removed https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#hierarchies-d3-hierarchy (It's changed, don't use `.layout` anymore - Tweak3r's answer addresses this)

Answer (score 24):

You need to include d3.layout.js in addition to d3.js; the layout module is in a separate file by default. You can also make a custom build of d3.js that includes everything you need in a single file.

Comment: true, but after including layout I get: d3.rebind is not a function error inside layout module. How to solve this?

Comment: I'm also having a d3.rebind is not a function error... I can only find one link to the layout file [here](https://gist.github.com/davo/4186300)... I'm using d3 v4.1.1, but can't find the version of the layout module...

Comment: Where is it [https://www.google.ru/search?q=d3.layout.js](https://www.google.ru/search?q=d3.layout.js)?

Answer (score 20):

You should use **d3.stack** instead.

Every symbol in D3 4.0 now shares a flat namespace rather than the nested one of D3 3.x. For example, **d3.scale.linear** is now **d3.scaleLinear**, and **d3.layout.treemap** is now **d3.treemap.**

For other d3.layout changes go here: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Comment: Sorry. This Answer is CORRECT for version 4

Answer (score 8):

(it's not the answer for this question)

For the people with the same error:

> d3.layout is undefined

In my case was the problem I just link directly to the latest release (v4)
https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js

With (v3) it is working again.
https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js