# d3.js v4 d3.layout.tree has been removed?

Tags: d3.js

After upgrading to d3.js v4.1.1, this line:

```
d3.layout.tree()
```

produces an error:

```
Cannot read property 'tree' of undefined
```

It seems like the tree layout has been removed from v4? https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md

The examples still use the v3 API:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025

Is the layout really gone or has it been renamed?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As of D3 v4.0 (June 2016), the tree layout has been renamed. See:

https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#hierarchies-d3-hierarchy

> Pursuant to the great namespace flattening:
>
> - d3.layout.cluster ↦ d3.cluster
> - d3.layout.hierarchy ↦ d3.hierarchy
> - d3.layout.pack ↦ d3.pack
> - d3.layout.partition ↦ d3.partition
> - **d3.layout.tree ↦ d3.tree**
> - d3.layout.treemap ↦ d3.treemap

Comment: Ugh this is obnoxious. Half or more of the code examples I find online use `.layout` and half don't and I wasn't sure if they were different or both correct or what...

Comment: @Andrew they are likely both correct, but were written for different versions of D3. D3 is always being improved because it's such a powerful library. The more you work with it, the easier it will become to adapt the old examples that you keep finding to the updated standards.

Another option that works well for me is to simply add "D3 V4" to the search (I use V5, but for you it would be V4). Typically, someone, somewhere, has already done the conversion for you and posted it online. Happy coding!